# Adding a custom summary protobuf for histograms

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorboard

I know that it is possible to add some custom summaries ***from outside the graph***:

```
summary = tf.Summary()
summary.value.add(tag='myVar',simple_value=myVar)
summary_writer.add_summary(summary, step)
```

However, I would like to do the same with histograms.

When I look at `summary_pb2.py` it seems that tf.Summary only accepts `Image`, `Audio` and `Value`.

How can I add histograms?

---

UPDATE: I am not looking for the standard way (adding histograms through an operation in the graph `tf.summary.histogram`).

I am looking for a way of adding protobuf summaries directly into the summarywriter without having to go through the graph. This is quite usual for scalars or images but I cannot find a way to do it for histograms.

Answer (score -1):

With TensorFlow TensorBoard, there are many ways to add summaries. To add a histogram summary, use [`tf.summary.histogram`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/summary/histogram). For the full list of all available summaries, check out: [Summary Operations](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/summary#Generation_of_Summaries). For an end-to-end example, check out the [Summaries and TensorBoard guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/summaries_and_tensorboard).